# Reading chosen Dropbox response in JQuery instead of Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector, dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm installing the Dropbox Chooser (https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser) in my web app and the example code is:

```
<input type="dropbox-chooser" name="selected-file" id="db-chooser"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("db-chooser").addEventListener("DbxChooserSuccess",
        function(e) {
            alert("Here's the chosen file: " + e.files[0].link)
        }, false);
</script>
```

I'd rather use jQuery, however, so I am trying:

```
$("#db-chooser").on('DbxChooserSuccess',function(event) { 
                alert("Here's the chosen file: " + event.files[0].link)
}
```

The alert does fire, but event does not contain a files[] node.  I did a console.log and couldn't find the data.  Is there a different way to do this?

Comment: try to `console.log(event)` and see where it is. might be `event.originalEvent`

Comment: Please fix your title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem sometime back when I was new to this API. I found a link at that time, which helped me understand a lot of things about this. [Here's the link to that.](http://tutorialzine.com/2012/11/dropbox-photo-crop/)

What the link says is, for accessing the `event.files[0]`, you'd have to check in `event.originalEvent`, not `event`. So, your code would look something like this :

```
$("#db-chooser").on('DbxChooserSuccess',function(event) { 
  alert("Here's the chosen file: " + event.originalEvent.files[0].link)
}
```

What actually happens is, when an event is initialised, jQuery copies almost all properties of the `originalEvent` (JS event) and creates its own `event` wrapper with custom properties. Along with it, it stores the `originalEvent` as a property so that some left out properties (such as `files[0]` in your case) can be accessed later. [From the jQuery Site](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/) :

> jQuery’s event system normalizes the event object according to W3C standards. The event object is guaranteed to be passed to the event handler. Most properties from the original event are copied over and normalized to the new event object.

That's why your `files[0]` property doesn't exist in jQuery's event. Hope this helps.

**PS** : There's a lot of nice stuff in that link. Do check it out :)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by David Fregoli, try `e.originalEvent.files[0].link`

http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler